# OnClick change color from another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have this code

```
 <script>
$('well').click(function () {
    $('span').css('background-color', '#000').css('color', '#000');
});
</script>
```

and I'm trying to make when I click on this "well" (from bootstrap) the color to a span from this well to be changed..

Comment: `well` is not a valid html tag. You need to valid jquery selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*if `well` is **class** than use `.well`*

```
$('.well').click(function () {
    $('span').css({backgroundColor:'#000', color:'#000'});
});
```

*if `well` is **id** than use `#well`*

```
$('#well').click(function () {
    $('span').css({backgroundColor:'#000', color:'#000'});
});
```

Also make sure to wrap your code in DOM ready:

```
jQuery(function( $ ) { // DOM is now read and ready to be manipulated and $ alias secured

   // Your $ jQuery code here

});
```

Comment: You can use `.css` infinite times.

Comment: You actually can use css two times. Alsoe you dont need curly brackets for the css command.

Comment: but dont you think its not the preffered way to add css

Comment: @Akshaypadwal what one thinks is irrelevant. Saying than one *cannot* when actually *can* is relevant.